# Can't Resign keyboard while tap on background?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to resign keyboard while tap on background but I cann't

first I have clicked on editable textfield and open keyboard then I have cliked on another textfield that is not editable after that I have cliked background but I cann't resign keyboard

here is my code

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{

    if(textField == insertcity)
    {
        [self.view endEditing:YES];
        citytable.hidden = NO;
        hoteltable.hidden = YES;
        [self SetDynamicHieghtofTbl:citytable andArr:cityarray];
    }

    if(textField == inserthotel)
    {
        [self.view endEditing:YES];
        hoteltable.hidden = NO;
        citytable.hidden = YES;
        [self SetDynamicHieghtofTbl:hoteltable andArr:hotelarray];
    }

    if(self.txt_validationCode.tag == 3)
    {
        //[self.view endEditing:NO];
    }

}

-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
   [textField resignFirstResponder];

   if(textField.tag == 3)
   {
        self.enteredCode = textField.text;
   }
}

- (void) backgroundTap: (UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    citytable.hidden = YES;
    hoteltable.hidden = YES;
    [self.txt_validationCode resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The simple way is to connect the delegate of UITextField to self (self.mytestField.delegate = self) and dismiss the keyboard in the method textFieldShouldReturn using [textField resignFirstResponder];

Another way to dismiss the keyboard is the following:

```
[self.view endEditing:YES];
```

Put

```
[self.view endEditing:YES];
```

where you would like to dismiss the keyboard (Button event, Touch event, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

I hope it's help you.

```
   - (void) backgroundTap: (UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
   {
     [self.view endEditing:YES];   // add this line in your code
    citytable.hidden = YES;
    hoteltable.hidden = YES;
    [self.txt_validationCode resignFirstResponder];
   }
```

Comment: Please explain your code and don't just post code hoping that they know what it means.